# Nutch crawl fails when run as a background process on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, nutch

When I run the Nutch crawl as a background process on Ubuntu in local mode, the Fetcher aborts with hung threads. The message is something like:

WARN  fetcher.Fetcher - Aborting with "X" hung threads.

I start off the script using nohup and & as I want to log off from the session and have the crawler still run on the server. Else, when the crawl finishes at a certain depth and when the crawldb is being updated, the SSH session times out. I've tried configuring "keep alive" messages without much help. The command is something like:

```
nohup ./bin/nutch crawl ....... &
```

Has anybody experienced this before? It seems to happen only when I use nohup or &.

Answer (score 1):

The hung threads message is logged by Fetcher class when some requests seem to hang, despite all intentions. 
In F[etcher.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/nutch/fetcher/Fetcher.java.html), lines 926-930 ::

```
  if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastRequestStart.get()) > timeout) {
    if (LOG.isWarnEnabled()) {
      LOG.warn("Aborting with "+activeThreads+" hung threads.");
    }
    return;
  }
```

The timeout for requests is defined by mapred.task.timeout and default value is 10 mins. You might increase it.. not sure if it will be a 100% clean fix.

When I had observed this phenomenon, I added loggers in the code to find for which url the request hung more than 10 mins and concluded that for large files this issue was seen that too when the server was taking more time for data transfer.

Comment: well it seems to work fine if I divide the seed and run multiple crawls. It must have a relation to the number of injected urls or domains. Anyway, are you talking about the file size that is being downloaded above?

Comment: that was what i inferred when i faced that issue. as u mentioned about seed division, it might also happen that having all urls at a time, some servers might not respond quickly after few requests r processed. if u re-produce and debug using the way i mentioned, u can figure out the problematic url/ host.

Comment: can you tell me exactly how you got the URLs logged in the above code? did you get it from the fetchQueue ?